# Expo Image Picker: Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker

I am currently working on a small app and I want load images from camera roll into the app. I've build a component to do so with the help of the Expo Image Picker at its documentation. Sadly, I always get the following warning in my expo client and I am not able to pick any images from the camera roll. It just stays as it is, when I click the button to select them.

My code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { View, Image, TouchableOpacity, PermissionsAndroid, Alert, Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons'

export default function ImageChooser() {
    const [imageSource, setImageSource] = useState([]);

    getPermissionAsync = async () => {
        
          const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
          }
          
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getPermissionAsync();
    }, []);
    
    _getPhotoLibrary = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
         allowsEditing: true,
         aspect: [4, 3]
        });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
         setImageSource({ image: result.uri });
        }
    }
    

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => _getPhotoLibrary()}>
                {!imageSource && <MaterialIcons name="add-a-photo" style={styles.icon} size={36} />}
                {/* {imageSource && <Image source={{uri:imageSource}} style={styles.image} />} */}
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingLeft: 20,
        paddingVertical: 10
    },    
    button: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#C6C6C8',
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    image: {
        width: 200,
        height: 150
    },
    icon: {
        color: '#C6C6C8'
    }
})
```

The warning I receive:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoImagePicker.default.launchImageLibraryAsync')]
* components/ImageChooser.js:23:23 in _getPhotoLibrary
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:189:16 in PromiseImpl$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:22 in doResolve
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:11 in Promise
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:188:15 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:211:38 in enqueue
- node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:238:8 in exports.async
* components/ImageChooser.js:23:23 in _getPhotoLibrary
* components/ImageChooser.js:36:61 in TouchableOpacity.props.onPress
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:691:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:628:6 in _receiveSignal
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:524:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:265:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:476:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:500:2 in invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:597:41 in executeDispatch
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:621:19 in executeDispatchesInOrder
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2521:28 in executeDispatchesAndRelease
* [native code]:null in forEach
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:836:4 in forEachAccumulated
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2546:20 in runEventsInBatch
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2702:18 in runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2639:35 in batchedUpdates$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17712:13 in batchedUpdates$1
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2767:27 in receiveTouches
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 5):

You are importing the `ImagePicker` incorrectly,

use `import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';`

Here is the reference documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/

Comment: For bare React Native `import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';` in the same fashion

Answer (score 1):

`Expo-image-picker` needs a plugin to get access to native code.
Make your you have included this in app.json. [Expo-image-picker docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/)

Also don't forget to rebuild app.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to let you share them with your friends."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Add "expo-image-picker" array to plgins array, in your app.json (app configuration file).
To learn more about app.json, read: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v46.0.0/config/app/

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check your EAS build in case there were issues there. It seems like the Native Module is always undefined, so could be a build issue

Try running `eas build:list` and navigating to the most recent build you're getting the error for. Then check the build pipeline steps.

`expo doctor` flagged an issue with the version of react-native i was using. Fixing this solved the error for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days I realized reason of this problem. It was related expo application. I tried my app in other device I could not faced this problem. After I removed expo and reinstalled my codes run succesfully.

Comment: removed expo meaning what? expo version in project upgrade?